# How can I change what details the Thunderbird email notification pop-up displays?

Tags: 11.10, thunderbird, email, notification

At the moment when I get a pop-up notification that I've received an email it is is the format:

```
-My email address
-Received 1 new message 
-Subject Line of email
-1st Line of email
```

How can I change this so that it also displays the email address/name of whoever sent me that email?

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 with Unity

Thanks for any help, I've gone through so many settings menu but have drawn a blank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was pointed in the right direction by a helpful soul. In Thunderbird go to:

Edit > Preferences > General > Show an alert > Customize

And select **Sender**